# Dynamically create template string in component

Tags: angular, typescript

If I have a string that contains '$', is it possible to replace them with inputs and have those inputs bound with ngModel to an array.
Example:

```
str = 'Load for $ seconds';
```

should be converted to:

```
str = 'Load for <input type="number" [(ndModel)]="data[0]"> seconds';
```

Comment: Why do you want this and what have you tried?

Comment: Is not 100% what you want but seems could be something similar you get using [Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form)

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you can do something like this

```
<label>Load for {{data[0]}} seconds</label>
```

Please share your code or explain it further.

Answer (score 0):

You can chieve using 2 ways data-binding right.

Template:

```
<input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="data[0]"/>

<input type="button" value="Get String" (click)="getString()"/>
```

Component:

```
data = [];

getString(){
  let str = "Load for "+ this.data[0];
  console.log(str);
}
```

Here is the stackBlitz Code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tedrwt